# uitableview in uiviewcontroller disappears in xcode 5

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am building an ios application for iPad, I used uitabbar to show some uiviewcontrollers, I added in some of these uiviewcontrollers an uitableview. Now when I first load the application the uitableview appears and show my data. if I opened an uiviewcontroller that is not in the uitabbar and return to the tab bar the table disappears !!! then if I choose another tab from uitabbar tabs and return to my tab (the one which has the uitable that disappears) the table show up !!! anyone know how can I fix this problem ?

I think it is an Storyboard/layout issue !!

any help will be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you are doing some kind of initialization in viewDidLoad which is not called again when you come back from a child view controller.

One quick fix could be to move that code to viewDidAppear method. If you further want to understand when either of this method was called or not, you could throw in some NSLog statements in each.